# Why do I get extra characters (arrow symbol) while fetching text through Tesseract?

Tags: tesseract

Whenever I fetch text in any language, the output has this extra character (arrow symbol), which is not there in the image. I'd like to understand, why it is present, and how to avoid these extra characters in the output.

[image: Output of Tesseract 4.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most likely the implicit page separator `\f`, which Notepad shows as that arrow. For some details on that topic, see: [What page separators are used in txt output by Tesseract 4.0.0?](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ.html#what-page-separators-are-used-in-txt-output-by-tesseract-400)

You can try to add `-c page_separator=""` to your config. You shouldn't see that symbol in your output then. Please notice, page breaks are entirely disabled then also.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot :) Could you please help me with the config file name also.. I see a lot of files under configs folder: alto, ambigs.train, api_config, etc,.. I added it in couple of files, but did not get the correct output; looks like I am not updating it in the correct file. Thanks!

Comment: How do you use Tesseract? There's no specific config file, it's just an additional option, you can set. For example, on the command line, you might use `tesseract myimage.png output`. Then, you simply add the above option, i.e. `tesseract myimage.png output -c page_separator=""`.